# Upper bound on the modulus of a power series and concentration inequalities for empirical processes

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

This is a research question I encountered when I as studying solutions of
Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral equations. It is related to a new statistical
method I am developing (which I cannot expose now) and requires good
concentration inequalities. Consider the Gamma density with parameters
$\theta<1$ and $\sigma>0$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{dG_{\theta}}{d\nu}\left(  x\right)  =f_{\theta}\left(  x\right)
=\left(  1-\theta\right)  ^{\sigma}\frac{e^{\theta x}x^{\sigma-1}e^{-x}%
}{\Gamma\left(  \sigma\right)  }1_{\left(  0,\infty\right)  }\left(  x\right)
,
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. Now let $\left\{  z_{j}\right\}
_{j=1}^{m}$ be $m$ indepenent but not identically distributed Gamma random
variables with densities given above and with paramters $\left\{  \left(
\theta_{i},\sigma\right)  \right\}  _{i=1}^{m}$, i.e., they have the same
scale parameter $\sigma$ (and we are in the simple case).

Define the transform
$$
w\left(  y,x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(  \sigma\right)
}{\Gamma\left(  \sigma+n\right)  }\frac{\left(  -yx\right)  ^{n}\exp\left(
\sqrt{-1}\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)  }{n!}\text{ for }y>0\text{ and }%
x\in\mathbb{R}%
$$
where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of reals, and the empirical process
$$
S_{m}\left(  y\right)  =\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m}w\left(  y,z_{i}\right)
-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\mathbb{E}\left[  w\left(  y,z_{i}\right)  \right]
,
$$
where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation operator. Note that $\left\{
S_{m}\left(  y\right)  \right\}  _{m\geq1}$ is complex-valued.

The method needs a good (or tight) concentration inequality for $\sup
_{y\in\left[  0,\gamma_{m}\right]  }\left\vert S_{m}\left(  y\right)
\right\vert $ for a positive sequence $\left\{  \gamma_{m}\right\}  _{m\geq1}$
such that $\gamma_{m}$ diverge to $\infty$ as quickly as possible, so that the
method has good finite sample property. Note that concentration inequalities
usually take the form
$$
\Pr\left(  \sup_{y\in\left[  0,\gamma_{m}\right]  }\left\vert S_{m}\left(
y\right)  \right\vert >\lambda\right)  \leq\exp\left(  -\frac{\phi\left(
\lambda\right)  }{V_{m}}\right)  \text{  for }\lambda>0,
$$
where $\phi\left(  \lambda\right)  $ is a positive, monotone function of
$\lambda$, and $V_{m}$ is a positive function of the variances of
$\left\vert w\left(  y,z_{i}\right)  \right\vert $'s and does not depend on
$\lambda$.

So, one way to bound $\sup_{y\in\left[  0,\gamma_{m}\right]
}\left\vert S_{m}\left(  y\right)  \right\vert $ probabilitistically is to
bound the moduli of $\sup_{y\in\left[  0,\gamma_{m}\right]  }\left\vert
w\left(  y,z_{i}\right)  \right\vert ^{2}$ uniformly in $y$ and $\left\{
z_{i}\right\}  _{i=1}^{m}$, so that we can bound $V_{m}$. The smaller $V_{m}$
is and the larger $\phi\left(  \lambda\right)  $, the better the concentration inequality.

I do not have any idea of how small the probability in the above concentration
inequality should be for each such sequence $\left\{  \gamma_{m}\right\}  _{m\geq
1}$ since I am totally new to the fields of concentration inequalities. After
reading a couple of papers on concentration inequalities by Dr. Stephane Boucheron
and Dr. Pascal Massart, I realized that as a first step I should try to bound the
moduli $\left\vert w\left(  y,x\right)  \right\vert $ or $\mathbb{E}\left[
\left\vert w\left(  y,z_{i}\right)  \right\vert \right]  ^{2}$ as tight as
possible for $y\in\left[  0,\gamma_{m}\right]  $.

The original version of the question was just to bound the moduli of the
following simple version of $w\left(  y,x\right)  $, which was
$$
w\left(  y\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^{n}\exp\left(  \sqrt{-1}%
\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)  }{\left(  n-1\right)  !n!}\text{ for }y>0.
$$

On the other hand, the method also involves identifying zeros of Laplace (and Fourier)
transforms of finite measures with unbounded support, which I did not get a
chance to post related questions, even though I am aware that Dr. Alexandre
Eremenko is a leading expert on analytic and meromorphic functions and has
make fundamental contributions to George Polya's conjectures.

**Update on June 15**: thanks to the connection with Bessel function pointed out by MTyson and Johannes Trost, I managed to obtain a concentration inequality involving only the variance of the process and its speed of convergence to 0 in probability. Will post to arxiv a draft that contains the computations for these.

**Update on June 17** in the construction, the function $w(y,x)$ should be $w(y,x)\cos(y)$. I was wondering what the range of $\cos(\log(m))$ is when $m$ ranges through the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. There is a post in math.stackexchange.com on the $\sup_{m \in \mathbb{N}}\sin(m)$, which is $1$, shown by noting that $\mathbb{Z} + 2 \pi \mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. However, I was not able to use this strategy to study the range of $\cos(\log(m))$. Any pointer is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update on June 21** An asymptotic upper bound as $x \to \infty$ for the following type of series $$F_{\rho}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^{\rho}$$ with $0< \rho \le 4$ and $x \ge 0$ is provided by indentity (8.07) in Section 8, Chapter 8 of ``Asymptotics and special functions'' by F.W.J. Olver. This series covers exponential function, Bessel function of order zero and the square root factorial series. It can be used to bound the function $w$ given above, even though not necessarily tight.

Comment: Your function looks a lot like a Bessel function, which have well-studied asymptotics.

Comment: Mathematica gives $(-1)^{1/4} \sqrt{y} I_{1}(2 (-1)^{1/4} \sqrt{y})$. $I_1$ is a modified Bessel function, see, e.g, https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25 , for a definition.

Comment: MTyson and Johannes Trost: thank you both for pointing out the  connection with Bessel function. This is enough for me to get a jump start on it. I also found out that Bessel functions have their own generating functions. By the way, do you two know a way to lower bound the moduli of the higher oder derivatives at a fixed point of an analytic function (in general)? Note that we always use Cauchy's formuar to upper bound them.

Comment: First, your "oscillating factor" can be removed by the change $z=ye^{i\pi/2}$, which gives a series with positive coefficients, and second you must explain what you mean by "good or tight estimate".

Comment: Dear Dr. Eremenko, thank you a lot for your comments. I have edited the original question into its general form relating to concentration inequalities of complex valued empirical process. I think it is highly nontrivial and requires joint knowledge from analytic functions and probability theory. Could you please vote it up? (It may be an open problem!)